# Correct order for prices per unit

Tags: measuring-units, money

In English, currencies should go before the number (i.e. €24.47). Other units should go after (i.e. 3 m<sup>2</sup>).

But what is the correct order when you mean to give a price per unit (using the slash sign preferably)?

- €24.47/m<sup>2</sup>
- 24.47 €/m<sup>2</sup>
- 24.47€/m<sup>2</sup>

Or is the slash so unusual that you never use it? If this has been asked, thank you for redirecting me. I couldn't find it.

Comment: If you mean 'square metre', the '2' should be a superscript - m². (I had to search the Character Map to find it!) The currency symbol is written before the number but pronounced after it (24 euros).

Comment: I edited the m² symbol for clarification, thank you for letting me know :D But my concern is about writing the combination of both units: the currency and the surface

Comment: @Ana In locales where the currency symbol goes after the amount, what is the convention for price per unit? Is it 24.47 €/m²?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, that's right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual order seems to be **£x per y** or **£x/y** i.e. **(currency symbol) (number) per (unit size)** or replace "per" with a slash.

Looking for examples, I find:

> on the BBC website **£211 per MWh** ([Business energy prices to be cut by half expected levels](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-62969427), BBC News, 21 September 2022)

> on a UK government site **£0.10 per kWh** ([Energy price cap explained](https://www.ofgem.gov.uk/information-consumers/energy-advice-households/check-if-energy-price-cap-affects-you), OFGEM, accessed 9 March 2023)

> at a British supermarket website **£2.10/kg** ([Silver Spoon Caster Sugar 2Kg](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/287281843), Tesco,  accessed 9 March 2023)

Answer (score 3):

Currency symbols are written before the number but pronounced after it (£1 = one pound). The [slash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html) can be used to represent *per*.

So, your first version is the correct one.